# Malloc works without type cast before malloc C/C++

Tags: c, pointers, memory, casting, malloc

I am learning about malloc function & I read this:

```
ptr= malloc(sizeof(int)*N)
```

Where `N` is the number of integers you want to create.

The only problem is what does ptr point at? The compiler needs to know what the pointer points at so that it can do pointer arithmetic correctly. In other words, the compiler can only interpret `ptr++` or `ptr=ptr+1` as an instruction to move on to the next integer if it knows that the ptr is a pointer to an integer.

This works as long as you define the variable ptr to be a pointer to the type of variable that you want to work with.

Unfortunately this raises the question of how malloc knows what the type of the pointer variable is - unfortunately it doesn't.

To solve this problem you can use a [TYPE cast](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm). This C play on words is a mechanism to force a value to a specific type. All you have to do is write the TYPE specifier in brackets before the value, i.e.:

```
ptr = (*int) malloc(sizeof(int)*N)
```

### Questions

- I have seen many places that they don't use `(*int)` before the malloc & even implementing a linked list with no errors. Why is that?
- Why do pointers need to know anything except the size of memory they are pointing to?

Comment: Did you read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You are entirely, hopelessly confusing syntax with semantics and you misunderstand the necessity of types. Unless you are **actually** doing pointer arithmetic on a pointer, the compiler doesn't need to know its exact type. (even more so because `void *` is subject to implicit conversion from and to every other object pointer type.) Also, **typecasting does *NOT* solve the problem.**

Comment: Note that if you're using Visual Studio, it will complain if you don't cast the return of malloc. Just ignore it.

Comment: @Inisheer Did you mean "compile C code with a C++ compiler" by "using Visual Studio"?

Comment: Pointers don't need to know the size of memory they are pointing to: they only need to know what type they are.  The compiler can pick this up from the declaration.  The cast is just for clarity: not really needed in C.  It is, however, required for C++.  BTW Your code is wrong.  It should be (int*) not (*int).

Comment: Thanks @GrijeshChauhan Can't say that understood it completely, but getting the hang of it. Need to study more. Sorry about the repost.

Comment: @Inisheer Well that's completely wrong, sorry. MSVC has a C compiler too -- you should be using that for compiling C code. **Do not EVER compile C code with a C++ compiler.** And yes, every C++ compiler reports an error, because C++ has a stricter type system than that of C.

Comment: @H2CO3 Correct. I don't disagree. VS supports C and C++. However, the editor will complain for some C code even if you are compiling C only. It's not a compiler issue. It's an IDE editor issue.

Comment: @Inisheer Ugh, that's harsh. So the editor in VS doesn't care if you are writing C or C++ code, it will treat it as C++ no matter what? (slow clap for Microsoft...)

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes. Regardless if you compile as C only. It will give visual cues suggesting malloc without a cast is an error. It doesn't necessarily treat ALL C code which may be invalid in C++ as errors. malloc is the one that comes to mind and causes a lot of new C devs to cast the return of malloc.

Comment: @Inisheer Yeah, indeed. (I am so happy and proud not to use any IDEs. They're just stupid.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Before you can use `ptr`, you have to declare it, and how you declare it is the pointer becomes.**

`malloc` returns `void *` that is implicitly converted to any type.

So, if you have to declare it like

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
```

`ptr` will point to an integer array, and if you declare like

```
char *ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
```

`ptr` will point to a char array, there is no need to cast.

It is advised not to cast a return value from `malloc`.

> But I have seen many places that they don't use (*int) before the
>   malloc & even I made a linked list with this and had no errors. Why is
>   that?

Because they (and you also surely) declared the variable previously as a pointer which stores the return value from `malloc`.

> why do pointers need to know anything except the size of memory they
>   are pointing to?

Because pointers are also used in pointer arithmetic, and that depends on the type it is pointed to.

Comment: And if you don't want to think about types, use the much better C idiom `ptr = malloc(N * sizeof(*ptr));` which allocates N items of any type, without you specifying it at allocation (only at declaration).

Answer (score 1):

Before allocating space for a pointer you need to declare the pointer

```
int *ptr;
```

Since return type of `malloc` is `void *`, it can be implicitly converted to any type. Hence

```
ptr= malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
```

will allocate space for `N` integers.

Answer (score 1):

> The only problem is what does ptr point at?

It points to a block of memory of size `sizeof(int) * N`.

> The compiler needs to know what the pointer points at so that it can do pointer arithmetic correctly.

You are not doing any pointer arithmetic in your code, so this does not apply. Returning `void *` from `malloc()` is fine because `void *` can be implicitly converted to and from any object pointer type.

Also note that **casting the return value to `(int *)` does *not* change the type of `ptr` itself.** So it doesn't to any good. If `ptr` was of type `void *`, then you couldn't perform pointer arithmetic on it even if you wrote

```
void *ptr;
ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
```

How should I explain this better? **A variable always has the same type,** regardless of which type of value you assign to it (e. g. in this case, assigning a `void *` to an `int *` is fine because there's an implicit conversion.)

This is why you **should not** cast the return value of `malloc()`: it has no benefits. It doesn't help correctness, it can hide errors, and it decreases readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
malloc returns pointer of type void and void type pointer is implicitly 
converted to any type so if you don't use typecast then it will also work
int *ptr;
ptr=malloc(sizeof(int)*N)
```

but if you use     malloc in c++ then you need to typecast.